# Work with class in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want create function with my type `test_type` in class `t`. My code:

```
type test_type = [`t1|`t2]

let get_types =
  function
   | `t1 -> "t1"
   | `t2 -> "t2";;

class type class_types =
  object
    method t_types : test_type
    method test : (string -> string -> test_type -> unit) -> unit
end;;

class t : class_types =
  object
    method test par1 ?(par2="no par2") ?(par3=`t1) () =
      print_endline("--->"^par1);
      print_endline("--->"^par2);
      print_endline("--->"^get_types par3)
end;;

let t_run = new t;;
t_run # test "parametr1" ~par3:`t2 ();;
```

is return error

```
The class type is not matched by the class type class_types
The first class type has no method t_types
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply your implementation of `t` lacks the method `t_types`, which is defined in the class type `class_types`.

In addition to this, method `test`'s type is `string -> ?par2: string -> ?par3: test_type -> unit -> unit`, which is incompatible with one at the class type.